# Как нейросети выдают результат не разбитый на заданные категории?

Tags: нейронные-сети

Например рисуют, пишут музыку, генерируют текст и т.д.
Была статья например о том как нейросети рисуют: https://habrahabr.ru/company/io/blog/262267/

Comment: Вообще-то как раз именно заданные категории мы видим в "произведениях" нейросетей. Мы видим категорию "глаз" в картинке зебры, состоящей из распознанных участков, на которых сеть увидела то, что обучена видеть - "глаз" - группу пикселей, образующую определённую форму и занимающих определённую по своей пропорции область. Мы слышим набор распознанных категорий, категорий распознанных из "шума" - если дело касается музыки, "Написанной" нейросетями. И т.д. Т.е. результат таки как раз разбит на категории. Иначе бы мы не увидели их "красоту".

Comment: @DimXenon Отлично, а почему не ответ?

Comment: Ответ должен быть лучше обоснован с приведёнными выкладками или хотя бы ссылками. Если будет время оформить ответ правильно - я его оформлю. Пока что - только комментарий.